# Primes of the form $p=x^4+y^4$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that
$$p = x^4+y^4$$
for some $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ ? What if we only require $x,y \in \Bbb Q$ ?

I know that $p = a^2+b^2$ with $a,b \in \Bbb Q$ iff $p = a^2+b^2$ with $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ (Davenport-Cassels) iff $p=2$ or $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. But $a$ and $b$ might not be squares. What are some references about this problem, which explain what is (un)known?

Comment: They are called [quartan primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartan_prime). See [A002645](http://oeis.org/A002645). I didn't find a proof in the references though.

Comment: Also, what about $x^3+y^3$ and $x^5+y^5$ ?

Comment: It seems an open question.

Comment: @Alphonse Divisible by $x+y$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut : thanks. For my comment, I forget to mention that of course here $x,y \in \Bbb Q$ and not necessarily $\in \Bbb Z$ (in which case your comment is helpful, but still it is not trivial!).

Comment: Notice that it was proved only in 1998 that [there are infinitely many primes of the form $a^2+y^4$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811185.pdf#page=2).

Comment: One expects that $x^3+y^3$ and $x^5+y^5$ are prime infinitely often (in cases where $x+y=1$). Proving this is well beyond current technology.

Comment: @MikeBennett : so you mean we expect that infinitely many primes have the form $p = x^3+(1-x)^3$ for some _rational_ number $x$ ?

Comment: Yes, one expects infinitely many primes of the form $3x^2-3x+1$ for $x$ integral. More precise versions of this follow from a conjecture of Bateman and Horn.